# r Converting from milliseconds to Hours and Minutes

Tags: r, time, converters

I have a set of times in milliseconds that I want to convert to hh: mm. An example dataset would be:

```
data <- c(5936500, 5438500, 3845400, 7439900, 5480200, 6903900)
```

I get this with manual calculation but it does not provide me the correct value for the minutes.

```
> data/1000/60/60

[1] 1.649028 1.510694 1.068167 2.066639 1.522278 1.917750
```

I tried this

```
format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+data, "%H:%M")
[1] "12:01" "17:41" "07:10" "21:38" "05:16" "16:45"
```

but that is not even close. Any thoughts on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero point we can get by doing:

```
strftime(as.POSIXlt.numeric(0, format="%OS", origin="1970-01-01") - 7200, format="%R")
# [1] "00:00"
```

Accordingly:

```
t.adj <- 0
res <- strftime(as.POSIXlt.numeric(v/1000, format="%OS", origin="1970-01-01") - t.adj*3600, 
                format="%R", tz="GMT")
res
# [1] "01:38" "01:30" "01:04" "02:03" "01:31" "01:55"
class(res)
# [1] "character"
```

The date doesn't matter, since:

```
class(res)
# [1] "character"
```

**Note,** that this solution might depend on your `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")`. In the solution above there is an optional hour adjustment `t.adj`*, however in my personal locale it's set to zero to yield the right values.

#### Data

```
v <- c(5936500, 5438500, 3845400, 7439900, 5480200, 6903900)
```

---

<sup>*To automate the localization you may want to look into the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/6574038).</sup>

Comment: When I run the first thing, I get this. How can I fix it?> strftime(as.POSIXlt.numeric(0, format="%OS", origin="1970-01-01") - 7200, format="%R")
[1] "18:00"

Comment: @amisos55 See update, maybe you need to adjust `t.adj`.

Answer (score 2):

```
hrs = data/(60 * 60 * 1000)
mins = (hrs %% 1) * 60
secs = (mins %% 1) * 60
paste(trunc(hrs), trunc(mins), round(secs, 2), sep = ":")
#[1] "1:38:56.5" "1:30:38.5" "1:4:5.4"   "2:3:59.9"  "1:31:20.2" "1:55:3.9"
```

Also,

```
library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(data/1000)
#[1] "1H 38M 56.5S"             "1H 30M 38.5S"             "1H 4M 5.40000000000009S" 
#[4] "2H 3M 59.8999999999996S"  "1H 31M 20.1999999999998S" "1H 55M 3.89999999999964S"
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to get numbers in this format --> 1:12 (HH:MM). is there any tweak that I can get from your functions?

Comment: I would like to get numbers as in this format (HH:MM) but again these numbers are incorrect  "12:01" "17:41" "07:10" "21:38" "05:16" "16:45"

Comment: in this part `paste(trunc(hrs), trunc(mins), round(secs, 2), sep = ":")` , I removed  `round(secs, 2)`. However, I want to attribute the seconds to closest minutes. Any thoughts on that?